# Indecomposability and $\mu$-stability for vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, coherent-sheaves

Consider vector bundles on any smooth projective variety $X$. It is easy to see $\mu$-stablility always implies indecomposability. On the contrary, I read the following argument for $X=\mathbb P^1$:

> Let $E$ be an indecomposable vector bundle on $\mathbb P^1$. By Harder-Narasimhan filtration and Serre duality, $E$ is $\mu$-stable.

I have difficulty in following this. We need to show for any subbundle $F\subset E$, it always satisfies $\mu(F)\leq \mu(E)$. This will imply that the Harder-Narasimhan filtration will necessarily to be trivial, but I don't know if this is sufficient. And I also don't know how to prove this. (Precisely I don't know how to use Serre duality here.)

And please do not use the fact that $E$ actually splits. (This is on the way to prove it)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC, what you want to do is assume that $E$ contains a destabilizing sub-bundle to get $0 \to F \to E \to Q \to 0$, and then use a maximality argument to show that $Q$ is locally free in this situation (i.e. show that if $F$ is maximal among destabilizing sub-bundles, then $Q$ is locally free). You then want to argue that $\operatorname{Ext}^1(Q,F) = \operatorname{Ext}^1(\mathcal O_\mathbb P^1, F \otimes Q^\vee) = H^1(\mathbb P^1, F \otimes Q^\vee) = H^0(\mathbb P^1, Q\otimes F^\vee(-2))$ vanishes (where I've written $=$ instead of $\cong$ everywhere, and the last step uses Serre duality).

Comment: @TabesBridges Many thanks! I believe this is the right way. Could you explain a little bit how to show $Q$ is locally free? It is not clear to me.

Comment: This is not my wheelhouse, but here's what I can tell you: Googling "locally free quotient" tells me that saturated subsheaves are the key idea here. More Googling tells me that a saturated subsheaf is one with torsion-free quotient (which equals locally free on a curve). The claim I've seen mentioned in several MSE and MO answers is that "saturating a subsheaf increases its slope," so that when assuming the existence of $F$, we may assume that it is maximal, and this apparently implies that $F$ is saturated. I cannot tell you how to fill in the details, but I bet Huybrechts-Lehn could.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thanks a lot! This is very helpful.